# How to read debug info from IIS logs

Tags: debugging, iis, logging, asp-classic

I'm maintaining an old asp classic application.
It uses Response.AppendToLog as its sole debug logging system.
I only debug it on my localhost so the logging files are on my harddrive in the %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles folder.

I'm looking for a tail-like program that shows these debug messages live. 
Maybe with a possibility to colour the messages based on a filter.

**Update:** I've started writing my own tail program in python using the info in [Recipe 157035](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/157035/). The logging lags behind by a minute approximately. Any ideas on improving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished it. Now all I have to do is `Response.AppendToLog("#message");` where every space or weird character in message is replaced by an underscore. Too bad it lags behind by a minute or so, but it's better than nothing.

```
import time, os, re

def tail_f(file):
    interval = 1.0

    while True:
        where = file.tell()
        line = file.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(interval)
            file.seek(where)
        else:
            yield line

def run():
    #Set the filename and open the file
    filename = r"C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex{0}.log".format(time.strftime("%y%m%d"))
    file = open(filename,'r')

    #Find the size of the file and move to the end
    st_results = os.stat(filename)
    st_size = st_results[6]
    file.seek(st_size)

    for line in tail_f(file):
        #ignore comments
        if line[0] != "#":
            line = line.strip()
            parts = line.split(" ")

            status = parts[10]
            if status == "304":
                continue

            when = parts[1]
            method = parts[3]
            path = parts[4]
            query = parts[5].split("|")[0].split("#")[0]

            if query == "-":
                query = ""
            elif query != "":
                query = "?"+query

            print when, method[0], status, path + query

            if status == "500":
                if parts[5].find("|") != -1:
                    errorparts = parts[5].replace("_", " ").split("|")[1:]
                    linenr = errorparts[0]
                    errornr = errorparts[1]
                    errormessage = errorparts[2]
                    print "Error {0} on line {1}\n{2}".format(errornr, linenr, errormessage)
            if parts[5].find("#") != -1:
                print "* "+("\n* ".join(parts[5].replace("_", " ").split("#")[1:]))

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel?  You could use [Snare for IIS](http://www.intersectalliance.com/projects/SnareIIS/index.html) (free) to log the information to [Kiwi's Syslog Daemon](http://www.kiwisyslog.com/kiwi-syslog-server-overview/) (not free).

Comment: I've tried both snare and epilog, but neither seems to be as easy to use as I'd like. I can't seem to get them to show me my logs.